# Installing pyqt5 with homebrew just for python2

Tags: homebrew, python

I don't have (and do not wish to have) python3 installed. I want to install `pyqt5` just for `python2`.

However every time I try to install pyqt5 with `homebrew` it keeps downloading python3 and trying to install it

Even using `brew install pyqt5 --without-python` which I would assume is an option created for this exact purpose, just produces exactly the same behaviour and starts downloading python3.

Any ideas?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, of course after trying to fix this for ages, I find the problem 5 min after posting this question!

For anyone else who runs into this:

The problem was that I didn't have `sip`, which is a requirement, and sip automatically installs for both versions of python too, and so it was sip trying to install python3. sip has its own version of `--without-python`, but that didn't get passed to it from the `pyqt5` install.

tl;dr - install sip separately first:

```
brew install sip --without-python
brew install pyqt5 --without-python
```